# How to skip the root view and go directly to displaying the second view in a UINavigationController hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am making a messaging app on ios that will have multiple folders for different types of messages. I will be using a navigation controller structure and would like the root view to be where the user can choose which folder to view. However, when I first segue to the navigation controller I would like the inbox folder view to display directly (ie. bypass the root view). Apples mail app has a similar structure (launches inbox when it opens). how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how the relationship is between the first view controller and the second view controller. If you want to do something like this, why don't you put your second view controller as the root controller of the **UINavigationController**.

Anyway, if you still want to do it the way you describe, you can just direct to the second view controller using the `viewDidLoad` method from your root view controller. But, it will make the UI looks clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

UIStoryboard *board = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

ViewController *controller1 = [board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstView"];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller1];

SecondViewController *secondView = [board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"];

[controller1 addChildViewController:secondView]; 

[self.window setRootViewController:navController];

return YES;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in ***didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*** of AppDelegate.m

```
UIStoryboard *MainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];
UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController*)[MainStoryboard
                                                               instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"YourStoryBoardID"];

NeededViewController *need=[MainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourStoryboardID"];         
[controller setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:need] animated:YES];
self.window.rootViewController=controller;
```